# avoid pushing duplicates to localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have a functioning code that adds the title of a class element to an array and then pushes it to a localStorage "database". Everything fine but i dont want to push elements there many times "if it is already there". Tried a couple of solutions but didnt quite get it. Any help is highly appreciated. Brain is melting..,

```
    var stores=[]
  jQuery('.additem').click(function() {
    var x = jQuery(this).closest('h4.title').text();
    if ((x == null) || (x == "") || (x == ($.inArray(this.x) > -1))) {
      jQuery(this).closest('.infobox').html('Already there or empty.');
      jQuery(this).closest('.infobox').show().delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        stores.push(x);
        console.log(stores);
        window.localStorage.setItem("database", stores.join(" + "));
        }
    });
```

Also tried with

```
(x == (stores.indexOf(this) > -1))
```

And a couple of something else.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overdoing it.
Doesn't this just work:

```
if ((x == null) || (x == "") || stores.indexOf(x) > -1) {
```

Comment: overdoing it is typical for me :) But found the problem.  It was me defining earlier for debugging var stores = [C] instead of empty. (Where C = the localStorage database. But thanks! Works now

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Set` which can be converted to and from an array for storage.

```
var s = new Set();
s.add(value);
localStorage.setItem('mySet',Array.from(s).toString())

var s = new Set(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mySet'))
```

Comment: can you specify? maybe an example?